# m3u8 video won't load in browser, CORB error with MIME type text/html

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome, video.js, m3u8

I want to open a m3u8 video (and preferably other video types as well) in an Angular web application. (or Ionic Angular).

I tried html video element like this (tried some other types or combinations of them as well)

````
```
<video [poster]="video.thumbnail" controls preload="none" playsinline>
    <source [src]="video.url" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    <source [src]="video.url" type="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl">
</video>
```
````

Which gave me this error (actually it looked like a warning, but it was the only thing) in chrome and didn't even looked liked it was even trying to load the video:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://*my video url* with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Then I tried using `video.js`. my component:

```
declare var videojs: any;
...
videoJSplayer = videojs(document.getElementById(id));
```

and added these to index.html:

```
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/7.0/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/7.0/video.min.js"></script>
```

It got fixed and was working fine in all desktop browsers (and chrome mobile simulations) and iphone (safari), even android Firefox, but still gives me the same error in **android chrome** while getting stuck in infinite loading loop this time.

I also tried iframe as was suggested in other questions, but it didn't work because I don't have access to source and 'X-Frame-Options' was 'sameorigin'.

Seems like I need a way to make it understand that it's not a text but a video. I'd appreciate it if someone can give some ideas about what am I doing wrong, or suggest another workaround. my `@angular/cli` version is `14.2.6` (and Ionic 6)

Answer (score 1):

Your two URL fragments reference "vjs.zencdn.net/7.0/".
I doubt that is fetching production-level code.

For video.js, I was taught to look at the release doc here:
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/releases

Notice the numerous releases that don't contain
the circled word 'Latest' after the release number, but
instead either show nothing or are circled 'Pre-release'.

So, based on that info, try fetching
'...vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.3/...'
since it's the most recent release labeled 'Latest'

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did this fix (and tried a few more version), but the problem was not solved.